# Angular ui-router unloads template when refreshed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, uiview, angular-ui-router

I want my default state to load home.html but nothing loads by default. When I click the link to Home, the state changes fine. If I type '/view2' into the url it changes to view2.html. But if I refresh the page or load the same url twice, everything unloads. What's happening?

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('app')
    .config(config);

  function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/home.html'
      })
      .state('view2', {
        url: '/view2',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/view2.html'
      })
  }
})();
```

here's the html

```
   <main ui-view></main>
    <a ui-sref="home">home</a>
    <a ui-sref="view2">view2</a>
```

Comment: what do you mean by loading the same url twice?

Comment: can you create a plunker or fiddle

Comment: Sorry I couldn't reply last night for some reason. So if I go to url "http://localhost:63342/restaurant/index.html#/" then it'll load my "home" state. If I refresh the page it'll unload the "home" state template. Same goes for any other state.